# Can't run jupyter notebook command in conda environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda

I am getting this error when I try to run `jupyter notebook` after activating an environment. Should I install `ipykernel` in the environment? I have already installed `nb_conda` in base. I don't face this issue when running `jupyter notebook` normally.

[image: unable to run jupyter notebook in conda envoronment]

I created the environment by running `conda create -n env_name python=3.7.1` and then ran `pip install -r requirements.txt`. These are the requirements installed:

[image]

Comment: Not to sound rude, but did you replace `env_name` with your desired environment name? Just thinking it might be launching in the wrong environment. That aside, I recently had a problem with ipykernal on windows where I had to run the install scripts. I would look at that too.

Comment: It's strange that you create your env with Python 3.7.1 but your logs say Python 3.6

Comment: Yeah, even I was thinking the same thing. Any idea why that could be?

Comment: Why use pip to install those packages? Have you seen https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment ? Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.